Internet becomes inaccessible during a browser download
I have built a new PC. I have updated my WiFi adapter drivers, flushed DNS.
The internet speed (download speeds tested on the desktop) is very fast, reaching 40-60Mbps. However, Whenever I start a download on ANY browser (Chrome/Firefox/Edge) the internet becomes inaccessible for anything else except the download. The download speeds are great but when the download is in progress, if I try to open/load any page/content on the browser or access internet from any other application, I get the "no internet" issue.
I'm at loss about what to do since I have already tried reinstalling network drivers, updating them, flushing DNS. Also, I noticed downloading on Steam doesn't produce the same effect.
Please help with this issue.

Does this happen only for downloads of browsers specifically, or for any big file download of a similar size? Does this happen on both Wi-Fi and Ethernet? Do you have a massive bufferbloat problem on your network? (run the Waveform Bufferbloat Test if you're not sure).

You mention that internet accesses fail while a download is going. Do you get any specific errors? 404 not found? Page timeouts? Just curious. If you have a second computer or a smartphone, is that other device also blocked from the internet during the download? Or is it just the computer doing the download? If other devices are also blocked, it sounds like a network problem. If just the one computer is blocked, the issue is probably local to your PC.

@sivs422, It's just the computer which is blocked off during the download. Internet on other devices on the same network works fine. The error is just  "DNS Probe finished. No internet".

@Spiff, Yes,It appears that issue happens only during large file size downloads from browsers. When I'm downloading from Torrent/Steam, There is no issue. I will try the Waveform Bufferfloat test and update here

Which Wi-Fi adapter (physical) did you put in the PC? Tried with wired Internet (while Wi-Fi is disconnected)?

@YisroelTech I have put the TP-Link Archer T4E V1 Wi-Fi Adapter. I haven't tried with wired internet because I don't have a LAN cable and my router is mounted quite out of reach physically

If you can get a LAN cable for testing at least it would be helpful. Also, have you tried a Network Reset (in Windows Setting under Network & Internet > Advanced network settings > Network Reset)?

@YisroelTech, I have tried Network Reset, But didn't help

@Spiff, I tried the Bufferbloat test and I got a "F". It says I suffer from bufferbloat. But I understand bufferbloat is a router issue, Correct? But this issue doesn't happen on my other devices (Laptop and mobile phones) connected to the same router

Bufferbloat can happen in any networking equipment, including your PC's Wi-Fi adapter. It's not specific to routers or modems, although that's usually where people find the problem.

@Spiff I suspect its the PC's Wi-Fi adapter since its local to my pc only. How do I fix this issue?

@Spiff So, I noticed I had 2 network adapters. One was a Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller and another was the TP-Link Wireless PCI Express Adapter. I disabled the Realtek Gaming Controller. My Bufferfloat tests have improved (Still C) : https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=662dfa8b-3fdd-4d03-a324-173e5751db73
The issue however still exists. Can't access internet during browser downloads. I tried following this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfIqPHPuOUs
But when I click on apply changes on the TCP Optimizer software, My PC crashes (BSOD) with rft64x64.sys.

Well, bufferbloat testing is inconclusive unless your device can fully saturate your broadband connection's download and upload bandwidth during the test. So I think you'd do well to plug into an Ethernet LAN port of your main router (actual Ethernet all the way; no Wi-Fi, MoCA, or powerline links in the path) and run the bufferbloat test that way, before you put too much weight on the test results.

@Vivek, since you say you have 2 adapters (the Realtek and the TP-Link) can you try to disable the TP-Link and re-enable the Realtek one and see if it helps? Another thing is to perhaps physically remove/disconnect one at a time to see if it's better with one of them by itself (maybe they interfere between each other...)
